# Checking Typescript Enum for value results in TS error OR doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

The following code does what I want it to do:

```
BallStatusTypes.safe === BallStatusTypes[status] ? 'ball' : 'ball-danger'
```

Despite giving me this error: `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'BallStatusTypes' and 'string' have no overlap.`

The following, error free code does NOT do what I want it to do:

```
status === BallStatusTypes.safe ? 'ball' : 'ball-danger'
```

The enum is:

```
export enum BallStatusTypes {
  danger = 1,
  safe = 2
}
```

How can I fix my code so that it does what I want it to do, without errors?

Comment: What's the type of the `status`? Create an example using https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this with:

```
export enum BallStatusTypes {
  danger = 'danger',
  safe = 'safe'
}
```

It seems I was having issues with the way enums create objects mapping to either a number or a string. And, typescript was unaware (when performing expressions on said value) of weather or not it should be comparing the numerical version or the string version of the status.